# Adding elements to a list / queue while iterating

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

From a leet-code question, but asking about the technicalities of mutable iterables and looping in this situation

This is just a general question. I know that generally you shouldn't modify an iterable that you are iterating over.

However, I was learning DSA, particularly DFS /BFS and I noticed that in BFS, typically you add the first node / element and  have a while loop that checks your queue isn't empty, and then you loop over the q at each 'level' and pop items from front, and then append any children node / neighbours if they exists throughout each iteration of the loop.

Maybe the weird behaviour lends itself to BFS, but the loop only iterates over the length of the original q before any popping / appending, and then checks the while condition (is empty) and then resumes with the new length of the queue.

In this instance, is it considered normal / acceptable to modify iterable / mutable variable?

```
    def levelOrder(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[List[int]]:
        res = []
        q = collections.deque()     # We want each layer, therefore we want BREADTH FIRST SEARCH

        if root:                    # if root is not null, add to queue
            q.append(root)

        while q:                    # while queue is non-empty
            val = []                # initialise list for node values
            print(f'len(q) = {len(q)}\n')
            for i in range(len(q)):     # loop through q while it is not empty
                print(f'i = {i}, len(q) = {len(q)}, q = {list(q)}\n')
                node = q.popleft()      # BFS, take first element in queue, add value to val
                val.append(node.val)
                if node.left:           # left to right, if left node exists, add to queue
                    q.append(node.left)
                if node.right:          # left to right, if right node exists, add to queue
                    q.append(node.right)

            res.append(val)             # once queue has  iterated through ORIGINAL nodes, we know we have   finished ONE LEVEL, add to results
        return res                      # once queue is empty
```

Answer (score 1):

You mustn't use an [**iterator**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Iterator) that was created before modifying the collection. In particular an iterator is used behind the scenes when you use the collection in `for element in my_list` kind of loops (same logic applies to lists, dicts, queues, strings, etc). This is because behind the scenes, such loop is expanded like:

```
my_list = [1, 3, 4]
iter = iter(my_list)
while True:
    try:
        element = next(iter)
    except StopIteration:
        break

    # your original loop's body goes here
    print(element)
```

`iter` is created before the loop starts. So when you modify the collection during looping, the `iter` variable might point to the next element in a collection with old unmodified state (or worse - garbage memory). It's bad, because such error is not usually catched by the Python itself - you'll just see strange behavior happen with your logic.

It's fine though to loop over indices using `for i in range(len(my_list))` and modify the collection, because `my_list[i]` will fetch the element from the *current* state of the collection. But there is still danger. `range(len(my_list))` is also computed before the loop starts. So if you remove elements from the collection, the loop over indices will still reach indices of the old length, so `my_list[i]` might access out of bounds. But compared to the previous case, you'll get a Python error if it happens.

Your code with the queue is just carefully designed, to *not* use the `i` index inside the loop body, it uses `pop`/`append` in the exact quantity to not go out of bounds ever